# Add corntab schedule for php controller function

Tags: php, cron, scheduler

I have php function and I want to run that command every day.
how can I execute php function to schedule to run every day using crontab please advice

Comment: so how do u execute this via command line?

Comment: You might need to check this URL https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs--net-8800

Comment: @DoaaMagdy : Thanks this is what i searched

Comment: @Doaa Magdy  : how to access a specific function inside controller using cron .pls advice

Comment: @Mox : * * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/user/pro_name/controllerphp&action=functionName >> /home/user/get.log here is my command its not working. how to access functionNamefrom cron

Comment: @dil I'm not sure what framework you're using, but it's quiet simple you call the controller method the same way you call it in browser /home/user/pro_name/controller/functionName (According to your routes settings)